# A flipped version of the <$ operator

Tags: haskell

I was using Parsec and trying to write it in an Applicative style, utilising the various nice infix operators that Applicative and Functor provide, when I came across `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a` (part of Functor).

For Parsec (or anything with an Applicative instance I would assume), this makes stuff like `pure x <* y` a bit shorter to write by just saying `x <$ y`.

What I was wondering now is whether there is any concrete reason for the absence of an operator like `($>) = flip (<$) :: Functor f => f a -> b -> f b`, which would allow me to express my parser `x *> pure y` in the neater form `x $> y`.

I know I could always define `$>` myself, but since there are both `<*` and `*>` and the notion of a dual / opposite / 'flipped thingie' appears quite ubiquitously in haskell, I thought it should be in the standard library together with `<$`.

Comment: Note that `x $> y` = `x *> pure y` = `pure y <* x` = `y <$ x`, because pure does not have side effects, and can be sequenced in any order. I usually write my parsers with the result on the left if I want to discard the result of the operation - but it's a preference thing if you really want it on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a trivial point, you mean `Functor f => f a -> b -> f b`.

Secondly, you go to [FP Complete's Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle), type in the desired type signature, and [discover that it is in the comonad and semigroupoids packages](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=Functor+f+%3D%3E+f+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+f+b).

I could not tell you, though, why it isn't in any more common package.  It seems a reasonable candidate for inclusion in a more standard location, such as `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to FP Complete's Hoogle, I hadn't been aware of that and going back to haskell.org's hoogle I noticed that it only searches the haskell-platform packages, which is why I didn't find it there.

Comment: There is some option you can give to haskell.org's Hoogle to make it search all of Hackage, but I can never remember what it is.  I don't know why they don't enable it by default.

Comment: `($>)` was [added](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/blame/master/Data/Functor.hs#L39) to `base` some time ago. We just have to wait for `base-4.7.0.0` to be released.